# Create an array of char from string array

Tags: c++, arrays

(language : C++)
I have this array:

```
 string myArray[] = {"Apple", "Ball", "Cat"};
```

Is it possible to store each element in the above array to a new array? Something like this.

```
  char word1[] = myArray[0];
  char word2[] = myArray[1];
  char word3[] = myArray[2];
```

I checked the above code, it would throw an error. How would I get this functionality? I cannot use two-dimensional array because I don't know the length of my word in my actual program. A file has the list of words, I would have to read it into the array and get the above string array.

Comment: Can you share with us what language you are using?

Comment: @Forty3 It is c++.

Comment: So `myArray` would have the line of text from the file and you want individual arrays for each word you encounter in the line? Can you shed some light on the end goal for this process?

Comment: Do you want to copy the data or do you just want a more readable access?

Comment: Why do you need to use character arrays?  See `std::string::c_str()`.  Look at the difficulty you are going through.  Stay with `std::string`.

Comment: Another alternative is to use `std::vector<std::string>`.  You can have a container (`std::vector`) of `std::string`.  Problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the example that you have posted, this is what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string myArray[] = {"Apple", "Ball", "Cat"};

    char test0[myArray[0].length()];
    strcpy(test0, myArray[0].c_str());
    char test1[myArray[1].length()];
    strcpy(test1, myArray[1].c_str());
    char test2[myArray[2].length()];
    strcpy(test2, myArray[2].c_str());

    int i=0;
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(test0)/sizeof(*test0)); i++)
        cout<<test0[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(test1)/sizeof(*test1)); i++)
        cout<<test1[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n";
    for(i=0; i<(sizeof(test2)/sizeof(*test2)); i++)
        cout<<test2[i]<<" ";
    cout<<"\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I have created character arrays `test0[]`, `test1[]` and `test2[]` of length equal to the corresponding string in `myArray[]`.  Then I used `strcpy()` to copy the corresponding string from `myArray[]` to the character array (`test0[]`, etc).  Finally, I just printed these new character arrays.

Working code [**here**](http://ideone.com/269kcr).

Note:  I am assuming that you are using GCC, since it supports [VLAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard).  If not, then you can use an array of particular length (or better yet, a `vector`).

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Standard C++ doesn't have VLAs, so `char test[str0.length()];` is not valid code.  Some compilers provide it as an extension, but it's not standard.

Comment: My understanding is that declared arrays must have a compile-time constant as their capacity.  Otherwise one must use the `new` operator and dynamically allocate the array.

Answer (score 0):

Old style (c++98/c++03):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string myArray[] = { "Apple", "Ball", "Cat" };
    char *firstString = new char[myArray[0].length() + 1];
    char *secondString = new char[myArray[1].length() + 1];
    char *thirdString = new char[myArray[2].length() + 1];

    strcpy(firstString, myArray[0].c_str());
    strcpy(secondString, myArray[1].c_str());
    strcpy(thirdString, myArray[2].c_str());

    std::cout << "firstString = " << firstString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "secondString = " << secondString << std::endl;
    std::cout << "thirdString = " << thirdString << std::endl;

    delete firstString;
    delete secondString;
    delete thirdString;

    return 0;
}
```

New style (c++11/14):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::string myArray[] = { "Apple", "Ball", "Cat" };
    std::unique_ptr<char> firstString{ new char[myArray[0].length() + 1] };
    std::unique_ptr<char> secondString{ new char[myArray[1].length() + 1]};
    std::unique_ptr<char> thirdString{ new char[myArray[2].length() + 1]};

    strcpy(firstString.get(), myArray[0].c_str());
    strcpy(secondString.get(), myArray[1].c_str());
    strcpy(thirdString.get(), myArray[2].c_str());

    std::cout << "firstString = " << firstString.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "secondString = " << secondString.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "thirdString = " << thirdString.get() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you please care to explain your C++11 approach?  Like, why you are using a `unique_ptr<>`, the `.get()` method, etc.?

Comment: Yeah, no problem.
Basically, std::unique_ptr is a safer replacement whenever you have something that you must create on the heap/dynamically (using the new operator). When the destructor for std::unique_ptr is called (when it falls out of scope, etc), it will automatically delete the resource held, so you never have to worry about a memory leak by forgetting to use delete. However, a std::unique_ptr is not the exact same thing as a raw pointer, and for functions that expect a raw pointer, you can use the .get() method to return the underlying raw pointer to the object you created.

Comment: So, can I use `unique_ptr<>` majority of the times when I would require the `new` operator?  Also, could you please point to some resources wherein I would learn about how to *apply* my C++11 knowledge?  I know C++, but not C++11, since I didn't practice it.  I would appreciate some resources to practice.

Comment: Yes! That's exactly right. Idiomatic C++11 means you try to use new and delete as scarcely as possible. C++11 is really an entirely new language, it has so many good features. I learned all of my C++11/14 knowledge from Scott Meyer's "Effective Modern C++". It is of course excellent, but expect to read it a few times to grasp the concepts. I found it extremely terse, and so much high level information is packed into such a small book that you really have to take it slow. In regards to truly using it, rewrite old projects using as much c++11 as you can, and apply the concepts from that book.